# Restrict generic type argument to NOT be another generic type argument in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to restrict a generic `T2` to **not** be `T1` or any of its subclasses?

I have the following two method overloads:

```
Sub Foo(Of T1, T2)(arg1 As T1, arg2 As T2) ' 1
Sub Foo(Of T)(arg1 As T, arg2 As T)        ' 2
```

Can I define these methods in any way, so that these code lines resolve as

```
Foo(1, True) ' 1
Foo(1, 1)    ' 2
```

Currently, the second call is ambiguous, unless I explicitly write

```
Foo(1, True)
Foo(Of Integer)(1, 1)
```

The type constraint `(Of T1, T2 As T1)` allows me to limit `T2` to `T1` and its subclasses. But can I write anything to achieve the opposite, so that the first overload only matches if `T2` is **not** `T1` (or any of its subclasses, but that's not even relevant for me)?

I can guarantee that in my case `T1` and `T2` will never be inherited or convertible in any direction. They are any two out of a pool of about a thousand classes, that's why I cannot create a non-generic cross product of all types.

Comment: All the generic type constraints are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters). That's C# documentation but VB supports the same constraints. If what you want is not listed there then it's not possible using generic type constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, my goal was to inhibit the use of two different type arguments by marking the method with two generics as `Obsolete`. And I actually found a way to do this by using an extension:

```
Public Class Bar

  Public Sub Foo(Of T)(arg1 As T, arg2 As T)
    DoStuff()
  End Sub

End Class

Public Module BarExtensions

  <Obsolete("A good explanation of what's wrong", True)>
  <Extension>
  Public Sub Foo(Of T1, T2)(bar As Bar, arg1 As T1, arg2 As T2)
    ' I could make this work, but any code calling this is most likely wrong
    Throw New ArgumentException()
  End Sub

End Module
```

This allows me to warn users that there's something fishy with their code:

```
Public Class Baz

  Public Sub WrongCodeDoingDangerousThings(bar As Bar)
    Dim x1 As Double = 1d
    Dim x2 As Double = 2d
    Dim x3 As Integer = 3

    bar.Foo(x1, x2) ' OK, no resolve conflict
    bar.Foo(x1, x3) ' Won't compile with "A good explanation of what's wrong"

    ' This works because conflicts between an extension and an instance
    ' method are automatically resolved in favor of the instance method
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Nice solution but your question probably should have been different.

Comment: @IvanH Yes and no. I guess I should've mentioned that I only want to mark one `Obsolete` which makes clear I can't go with your solution. But technically I was already asking explicitly about two separate methods. Sorry for the confusion, and I'm sure both our answers have good use depending on the actual use case. If the two-generic method has to actually do something, it will not have access to private members etc, and your answer fits the needs.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you require doesn't seem to be possible because any restriction is for a single parameter not a combination.
There is a solution with decision in runtime instead of in compile time.

**You want:**

```
Sub Foo(Of T1, T2)(arg1 As T1, arg2 As T2) 
   Do1()
End Sub

Sub Foo(Of T)(arg1 As T, arg2 As T)        
   Do2()
End Sub
```

**You can:**

```
Sub Foo(Of T1, T2)(arg1 As T1, arg2 As T2) 
    If arg1.GetType() is arg2.GetType() Then
       Do2()
    else
       Do1()
    End If          
End Sub
```

It is not very nice and a bit slower but solves the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to inhibit people from using two different types by marking the one with two generics `Obsolete` with a meaningful message. Hence I needed two different methods, so I can mark the one with two generics with `<Obsolete("You do not want to do this", True)>`. I found a way though, will share soon.